# Annoying Screen / Cursor Shifting Issue With Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started using the Visual Studio Code interface, however, for some reason, my cursor keeps automatically jumping to the last character of the line I click on. The regular visual studio app performs this same action, but with a double click instead, eliminating screen shift if I accidentally miss click.

For ex.

If I'm working with an svg or a long line of code, any time I click on a different line where there is empty space, my cursor automatically moves to the end of that line I clicked on.

I've already tried disabling a few settings, but nothing has worked yet. Does anyone know what setting I could find to prevent this? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: VSC will not insert spaces/tabs up to the clicked location, so the best location on that line is the last character

Comment: Welcome! Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: @starball Thanks for the reply. I've disabled all of my extensions and reloaded twice but still nothing. Is this just an integrated part of VSC I can't change?

Comment: this happens even if you click on the beginning of a non-empty line?